# Force showing system tray notification balloons

Tags: c++, winapi

My application (C++ WinAPI) creates an icon in the system tray. I have set a tooltip text for this icon, so that when a user places a mouse cursor over the icon, this text shows.

But I want to programmatically show different balloon notications when certan events occur and at the same time keep that behavior of showing the constant notification message when a user places a mouse over the icon.

How to achieve this in C++ WinAPI?

Thanks

Alexander Smirnov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the balloon using the `.szInfo` (message) and `.szInfoTitle` (title) members of the [`NOTIFYICONDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352(VS.85).aspx) structure that you send to `Shell_NotifyIcon()`. The mouse-over tooltip text is set in `.szTip` so this is independent of the balloon - as long as you keep `.szTip` to the tooltip you want you can do as much `NIM_MODIFY` calls to change the balloon while not changing anything to the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.stromcode.com/2008/03/02/cwin32-the-system-tray-and-balloon-tips/